# Firebase Cloud Function database snapShot

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to write a Firebase Cloud Function that takes all the users from my database and edits values within them. However, in order to do that I need a quick way for the code in my Cloud function to receive all of the user-ids from the database. For now, I have the function print the data it gets from the database so I know what I am working with.

The result is this:

```
{"WNGOuQqZhZSo5UFovgmgEAVX3Gz1":{"displayName":"jack","email":"test2@gmail.com"},"aRaZVJorkYNwCSzAbMkNJiGwzJm2":{"displayName":"testing","email":"testing@gmail.com"}}
```

I just need the two userIds instead.

This is the part of database I am working with:
[image: part of database I am working with]

This is the code:
[image: the code]

If anyone knows what I need to change I would really appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: Kindly add the code and not the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to have a for - in loop over `value`. Below is the pseudocode -

```
var value = snapShot.val();

let namesArray = [];

for (var key in value) {
    if (value.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        namesArray.push(key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As with what jaibatrik said, you need to iterate over your objects.

You can't get the key without fetching the whole object.

In addition to running a for loop you can run a `forEach` over the snapshot.

```
 const uids = [];

 snapShot.forEach(single => {
    uids.push(single.key);
 });
```

The other option is to get all the keys from the `snapShot.val()` object.

```
 const value = snapShot.val();

 const uids = Object.keys(value);
```

Both ways are effectivly the same thing, just a preference on which way you prefer to do things